# What happens to an expired weak_ptr in a map

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, weak-ptr

I would like to understand what happens to an entry (of type boost::weak_ptr) in a map whose weak_ptr has expired. Does the corresponding entry in the map get automatically deleted?

The key is an integer and corresponding value is a weak_ptr.

Sample code I wrote, but could not get it to compile

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <map>
    #include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>

    using namespace std;

    class Foo : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<Foo> {
    public:
        Foo(int n = 0) : bar(n) {
            std::cout << "Foo: constructor, bar = " << bar << '\n';
        }
        ~Foo() {
            std::cout << "Foo: destructor, bar = " << bar << '\n';
        }
        int getBar() const { return bar; }
        boost::shared_ptr<Foo> inc_ref() {
            return shared_from_this();
        }
    private:
            int bar;
    };

    std::map<int, boost::weak_ptr<Foo> > mappy;

    int main()
    {
        boost::shared_ptr<Foo> sptr(new Foo(1));

        std::pair<std::map<int, boost::weak_ptr<Foo> >::iterator, bool> res = 
mappy.insert(std::make_pair(10, sptr));

        if (!res.second ) {
            cout << "key already exists "
                             << " with value " << (res.first)->second << "\n";
        } else {
            cout << "created key" << "\n";
        }

        std::cout << "sptr use count  "<< sptr.use_count() << '\n';

        sptr.reset();

        std::cout << "sptr use count  "<< sptr.use_count() << '\n';

        std::map<int, boost::weak_ptr<Foo>, std::less<int> >::iterator map_itr = mappy.find(10);
        if (map_itr == mappy.end()) {
            cout << "Entry removed" << "\n";
        } else {
            cout << "Entry found: " << map_itr << "\n";
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

The documentation of WeakSet in Java says that the entry is removed when the weak_ptr expires. So thought of checking if the map exhibits a similar (or undefined) behavior.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Does the corresponding entry in the map get automatically deleted?

No, it doesn't. The entry will continue to exist. The map and the `shared_ptr` are entirely unrelated entities. All the destruction of the last `shared_ptr` does is free memory.

The advantage of `weak_ptr` is that the `weak_ptr` will be able to know if the `shared_ptr` has been deleted or not. That's what the [`expired()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/smart_ptr/weak_ptr.htm#expired) and [`lock()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/smart_ptr/weak_ptr.htm#lock) member functions are for. Once it's expired though, it is still up to you to remove it from the map.

Comment: Do any of the std containers automatically remove the expired weak_ptr as an entry?

Comment: @Maddy No. You could implement that machinery yourself (write a custom deleter that keeps a reference to the map that searches for the corresponding `weak_ptr`, etc.) but that sounds extremely heavy-handed and is almost certainly not what you want to do anyway.

Answer (score 3):

> Does the corresponding entry in the map get automatically deleted?

Definitely not. To achieve that `std::map::find()` would have to modify the map removing expired elements, which it cannot do due to contract. Especially `const` version.